# How to disable jumping to last line and in pantheon-terminal?

Tags: pantheon-terminal

I have been using elementry OS for some time. I use terminal a lot. I like the simplicity of pantheon-terminal but some behavior of terminal irritates me. Whenever, some commands are issues (which has a long list of lines), the terminal only displays the last few lines and does not allow me to see the top lines. When I use scroll bar to view top lines, it goes back to last line automatically. How do I disable this behaviors?

Also, how do I use backspace to delete line in terminal? Currently, backspace deletes only one letter.

Answer (score 0):

In other terminal e.g. gnome-terminal, that is called `Scroll on output` and you can disable it. I can't find any option to disable it on pantheon-terminal though.

For deleting line in terminal, position the cursor to the end of the line and press `Ctrl + u`.